# Login Incorrect Solaris 10

Tags: solaris, solaris-10

I've been trying to update Bash on Solaris 10 from Version 3 to 4.2 However, in the process i seem to have broken one of the custom accounts.

To install bash i've been making modifications to the /etc/passwd file when i was experiencing "Invalid Shell" errors. However i'm now getting a "Login Incorrect" error which i can't seem to get passed.

I'm able to login to the machine as root, the profile for the custom user appears to still exist however i can not seem to stop this error from occurring.

Does anyone have any ideas what might have went wrong here?

Comment: What does the user's line in the passwd file look like?  Are other users affected?  What is in the log?

Comment: I'm able to login to the machine as root at the moment. Which log file are you referring to (I'm a fairly new Solaris user)

Comment: For additional info, when i attempt to change the password for the user. It shows up as "User Unknown"

Comment: Resolved.

There was a syntax error on the line of the user in question. 

I used the "pwconv" command to identify this syntax error. Fixed the error and all was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. There was a syntax error on the line of the user in question. I used the "pwconv" command to identify this syntax error. Fixed the error and all was resolved.